MacBook speakers crackling and laptop turns off when unplugged even though the battery is full
I hope someone can help me with this issue.
About a month ago my MacBook Pro Mid 2012 speakers started to rattle badly, specially with bass sounds, and today the laptop started to turn off instantly when unplugged (as if it didn't have a battery). The battery shows 100% charged though.
I run the Apple hardware test and says everything is ok. I have also reset the NVRAM and the SMC, but nothing has changed.
My MacBook charger insulation broke a few months ago and I have been using it with some tape around, don't know if it may have caused any of the issues.
Does anyone know what it could be? I hope I could fix it. Thank you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you device is 12 years old and saw regular use, the battery could well be dead.

Hi, thank you for your answer. The battery has a 75% battery health now according to the Battery Health 2 app
